# Freeze the last frame of a xcode image animation

Tags: xcode, image, animation, uiimageview, freeze

I try to solve a problem for a few weeks, but I don't find answer.
I try to get that the last frame freeze when the animation ends.

This is my animation code:

```
 -(IBAction)play {
    image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"], 
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],nil];
    
    [image setAnimationRepeatCount: 1];
    image.animationDuration = 0.5;
    
    [image startAnimating];

    
}

-(IBAction)stop{
   [image stopAnimating];
}
```

When I press the button play, the animation runs and when I press button stop, the animation stop and disapear the image.

I like do this thing without stop button, when the animation end, the last frame is visible.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the easiest way to do it, but it works. Here you are:

```
- (IBAction)stop {
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, screenSize.width, screenSize.height, 8, 4 * (int)screenSize.width, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, screenSize.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    [(CALayer*)self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *lastFrame = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    image.image = lastFrame;
    [lastFrame release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just do:

```
-(IBAction)stop {
     [image stopAnimating];
     image.image = [image.animationImages objectAtIndex:12]; //or 0 to jump to the first image
}
```

Worked for me:)